# How to use AVCapture Zoom in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I am working on AVCapture camera to capture images/videos.It is working fine.But i have problem to implement the zoom feature.

I am using below code to achieve zoom,

```
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(setVideoZoomFactor:)]
         && device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor >= zoomLevel) {
         // iOS 7.x with compatible hardware
         if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
             [device setVideoZoomFactor:zoomLevel];
             [device unlockForConfiguration];
         }
     }
```

Above code is working fine in all devices except iPhone4s.It says max. zoom factor is 1.0000.So how can i achieve the zoom feature in iPhone4s.

Comment: iphone 4s hardware not supported for zoom

Comment: Ok.But native iPhone 4s camera supports zoom.How is this possible?